# How can I effectively organize data from a MySQL join query into an associative array?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to organize the result of a MySQL query that joins one table that provides a first name and last name, with a table that provides interval statistics. I have the query as follows:

```
$stat_query = "SELECT
CONCAT(rep_master.first_name, ' ', rep_master.last_name), tour_1.total_calls, tour_1.acw, tour_1.revenue, tour_1.envelopes, tour_1.pens, tour_1.other
FROM rep_master
LEFT JOIN tour_1
ON rep_master.id = tour_1.id
WHERE rep_master.leader = 'LENTSCH'";

$stat_result = $mysqli -> query($stat_query);
while ($stat_row = $stat_result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($stat_row as $i) {
        array_push($stat_array, $i);
        echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
};
```

This produces a nice little table that lists the statistics for each representative, but I need to be able to organize the information so that I can display it in a pre-formatted table. My thought is that I should create multiple instances of a PHP "representative" class, or at the very least have an associative array. What I want to have is:

```
Representative Name
  - Total Calls
  - ACW
  - Revenue
  - Envelopes
  - Pens
  - Other
```

I should also mention that there are four intervals for which data needs to be organized (tour_1, tour_2, tour_3, tour_4). Any thoughts or suggestions on how to achieve this? Take a look at my [prototype](http://rvold.com/prototype/prototype_managerpage.php) development page thus far for details.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: Use PDO and [`PDO::FETCH_GROUP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).